# Number input shortcut key incrementers and decrementers

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Is there a way to detect when a value in a number field is being increased or decreased? I would like that to determine wether or not to add or subtract an extra amount e.g. shit is down so +5 if increasing etc.

I have:

```
var oldVal = input.val();
input.change(function() {
    var newVal = input.val();
    if (newVal > oldVal) {
        if (shiftIsDown) {
            input.val(parseInt(input.val()) + 5);
        }
    }
    if (newVal < oldVal) {
        if (shiftIsDown) {
            input.val(parseInt(input.val()) - 5);
        }
    }
    oldVal = newVal;
})
```

But it behaves strangely and does'nt really work.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
var oldVal = input.val();
input.change(function(e) {
 var newVal = input.val();
 var shiftIsDown = e.shiftKey ? true : false;
 if(shiftIsDown) {
    if(newVal > oldVal)
        input.val(parseInt(input.val()) + 5);
    else if (newVal < oldVal)
        input.val(parseInt(input.val()) - 5);
 }
 oldVal = newVal;
})
```

*assuming `input` is a jquery object.*

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5SQN8/) :

```
var input = $("#input");
var oldVal = input.val();
var newVal = input.val();

input.keyup(function () {
    oldVal = newVal;
    newVal = input.val();
});

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 16) {
            if (newVal > oldVal) {
            input.val(parseInt(input.val()) + 5);
    }
    if (newVal < oldVal) {
            input.val(parseInt(input.val()) - 5);
    }
    }
});
```

keyup function is for listening of input changes

keydown functions is for shift down listening - `(e.keyCode == 16)` is equals to pressing shift event, so when you ever press shift the input val is being changing